# SQLException was Unhandled. Viewing Excel File in GridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, gridview, datagridview

I've been doing a C# project where I browse and view an Excel File into a gridview. However, there is an error message which I don't understand. Can someone please help me out on this.

This is the code I used:

```
private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", textBoxFileName.Text);

    string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

This is the error message:

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing 
a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, 
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to Excel via a `SqlConnection`.

To connect to Excel use `OleDBConnection`:

```
private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", textBoxFileName.Text)
   var objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

   objConn.Open(); 

   OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);

   OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(); 

   objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect; 

   DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet(); 

   objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1); 

   objConn.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Usually so, but in his case, he wants to use JET to connect to an Excel file. This doesn't work using `SqlConnection` or `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Great. Now that you've completely changed your answer, my comment seems a bit off. ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - :-P I posted my original answer based on the error message, then when I re-read the question I noticed he was using Excel and amended accordingly.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I did what you suggested me to do (To connect to Excel use OleDBConnection) and the previous error was gone. But, there is a new error message keeps on displaying. The error message is "External table is not in the expected format.". What might be the cause of the problem? If I may ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `SqlConnection` or `SqlDataAdapter` for ODBC or JET connections. Use `OleDbConnection` or `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Please also make sure to dispose of connections and resources in a timely manner. Using the `using` statement is recommended here.

```
private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", textBoxFileName.Text);
   DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

   using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
       objConn.Open(); 

       using (OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn))
       using (OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter())
       {
           objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;    
           objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1); 
       }
   } 
}
```